# Cannot read property undefined of undefined in select items

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in my jsp file, this table have a column with `N` `radiobuttons` with the property `name="radioA"`, then I'm iterating for each `radiobutton` to find the selected `radiobutton`:

```
function findRadioSelected(){
    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("radioA");
    for(var y = 0; y < radioButtons.length; y++){
        if(radioButtons[y].checked){
            var cont = y;
            return cont;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

In another column on the same table, I have a `<select>` item with `N` options, the `id` property for each `select` item is [0-N], because I need to find the `radiobutton` `checked`, and then get the `select` item matched for the `radiobutton`:

```
function buscarActualizarFitir(){
    var counts = findRadioSelected();  //Getting the number of radiobutton checked
    alert(counts);
    if(counts >= 0){
        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("radioA");
        var idFitir = radioButtons[counts].id;  //Geting the id of the radiobutton checked
        var e = document.getElementById(counts).selectedIndex;  //Getting the selected index of the select item
        var x = document.getElementById(counts).options;  //Getting the options of the select item
        var idSuperGrupo = x[e].index;  //Error Line, I'm trying to get the number of the index of the option seleted in the select item...
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

[EDIT]:

The id of the `<select>` item, actually exists.

```js
function findRadioSelected(){
    var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("radioA");
    for(var y = 0; y < radioButtons.length; y++){
        if(radioButtons[y].checked){
            var cont = y;
            return cont;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function buscarActualizarFitir(){
    var counts = findRadioSelected();  //Getting the number of radiobutton checked
    alert(counts);
    if(counts >= 0){
        var radioButtons = document.getElementsByName("radioA");
        var idFitir = radioButtons[counts].id;  //Geting the id of the radiobutton checked
        var e = document.getElementById(counts).selectedIndex;  //Getting the selected index of the select item
        var x = document.getElementById(counts).options;  //Getting the options of the select item
        var idSuperGrupo = x[e].index;  //Error Line, I'm trying to get the number of the index of the option seleted in the select item...
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" id="botonConsultar" onclick="buscarActualizarFitir();"
   <span>Action!</span>
  </button>
    <table align="center">
            <tr style="height: 40px;">
              <th align="center" width="25%">Selecci&oacute;n</th>
              <th align="center" width="25%">Unidad de Negocio</th>
              <th align="center" width="25%">Producto (Supergrupo)</th>
              <th align="center" width="25%">Producto (Subgrupo)</th>
            </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: rgb(249,249,249)">
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <p><input id='255' name="radioA" value='255' type="radio" /></p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    ASDASDASDASD
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="0">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="sub0">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>


                <tr style="background-color: rgb(240,241,241)">
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <p><input id='194' name="radioA" value='194' type="radio" /></p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    ASDASDASDASD
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="1">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="sub1">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>


                <tr style="background-color: rgb(249,249,249)">
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <p><input id='1003' name="radioA" value='1003' type="radio" /></p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    ASDASDASD
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="2">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="sub2">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>


                <tr style="background-color: rgb(240,241,241)">
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <p><input id='1002' name="radioA" value='1002' type="radio" /></p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    ASDASDASDASD
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="3">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;" width="25%">
                    <select id="sub3">
                      <!-- OPTIONS -->
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
           </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? Using the snippets on SO or something like jsfiddle

Comment: Need to see the html too.

Comment: Also, is `e` not the index you are trying to get in idSuperGrupo

Comment: Sounds like `document.getElementById(counts)` isn't returning anything. Need the HTML to figure out why.

Comment: I added a snnipet @nem035